# Как засунуть ссылку на файл, который будет отображаться через контроллер?

Tags: php

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace ilari\App\Controller;

use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
use Laminas\Diactoros\Response;

class HomeController
{
    public function __invoke(ServerRequestInterface $request): ResponseInterface
    {
        $response = new Response();
        $response->getBody()->write("<h1>Hello World!</h1>");
        return $response;
    }

}
```

меня интересует вот эта строка:

```
$response->getBody()->write("<h1>Hello World!</h1>");
```

как в неё поместить ссылку на файл, к примеру index.php, раньше писал не ООП код, и писал вот так:

```
<?php include 'assets/views/nav-bar.php'; ?>
```

Comment: Очевидно тут так не делается. Паттерн MVC подразумевает другой подход к выводу данных. Есть специальная сущность View, в которой происходит вывод. Этот вывод можно записать затем в body ответа.

Comment: @u_mulder, как это отобразить с помощью кода?

Comment: Открыть и изучить документацию по используемому фреймворку.

Answer (score 0):

Есть документация по [include](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.include.php)
Вы можете подключить его в теле метода, если у вас там процедурный код без функций и классов.
Если у вас там `echo`, то можно вывести это в буфер обмена и занести в переменную

```
ob_start();

include 'assets/views/nav-bar.php'; //здесь можно накосячить с путями, не рекомендую

$out = ob_get_clean();
$response->getBody()->write($out);
```

но по хорошему, Вам надо переделать `assets/views/nav-bar.php` в класс, один из методов которого возвращает вам необходимые данные и подключить его

```
use assets\views\NavBarClass

$navBar = new NavBarClass();
$response->getBody()->write($navBar->getBody);
```